# How to start an Activity while overriding one of it's methods?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, overriding

I have two classes, both of which extend `Activity`.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout activityLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        activityLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
        activityLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        activityLayout.setPadding(16, 16, 16, 16);
        activityLayout.addView(new Button(this));
        setContentView(activityLayout);

        new Permissions() {
            @Override
            public void onPermissionRefused() {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Refused", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }.requestPermissions(this);
    }
}
```

Permissions.java

```
public class Permissions extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Dialog); // Custom theme to make Activity like a Dialog
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        onPermissionRefused();
    }

    public void requestPermissions(Activity activity, String... permissions) {
        startActivity(new Intent(activity, Permissions.class));
    }

    public void onPermissionRefused() {

    }
}
```

What I want to do is start the `Permissions` `Activity` while overriding it's `onPermissionRefused()` method. However, neither of the two ways I've tried work.

```
new Permissions() {
            @Override
            public void onPermissionRefused() {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Refused", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }.requestPermissions(this);
```

Doesn't pass the override and swapping that code out with: `startActivity(new Intent(this, Permissions.class));` doesn't even allow me to override the method. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. Create a subclass of Permissions

```
class MyPermissionsActivity extends Permissions {
            @Override
            public void onPermissionRefused() {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Refused", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

}
```

Step 2. Declare that subclass in your application manifest

Step 3. Launch the activity as follows:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, MyPermissionsActivity.class);
currentActivity.startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  Activities have to be declared in the manifest, you can't declare an anonymous inner class that way (and even if you could, it wouldn't have the right constructor because of the implicit reference to parent).  If you need that, make a real subclass, and pass any necessary variables via intent.